# Android frequently saving data to database and internal storage health

Tags: android, memory, storage, local-storage, internal

This is probably a pointless worry, but here it goes.

I am recording data that is saved to a database every 1 minute, and as far as my knowledge of hardware goes am wondering if repeated write cycles over time would cause any damage to internal storage. Similiar thought to how repeated writes to cells in an SSD will eventually render said cells unusable. Is there such a worry?